# Getting number keyboard on phone, when focus on text input field

Tags: android, html, input, numeric

I have an input field that needs to be of type, text. But I want the keyboard that appears on a phone to be the numeric one. How can this be achieved? I've tried the following:

```
<input class="input-number-noarrows" name="ASETid" id="txtHours" 
style="width:100%;height:75px;font-size: 60px;text-align:center;"
focus-me="focusInput" ng-tooltip="Enter hours" ng-model="clone.hoursNoTotal"
ng-change="resetTotalHoursForDelevery(clone.hoursNoTotal)" 
ng-keydown="controlForNumber($event)" type="text" pattern="\d*" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: I've now also tried the inputmode="numeric" attribute but it has no effect

Comment: Is this really just impossible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to replace

```
type="text"
```

with

```
type="number"
```

Comment: It needs to be of type="text" for reasons.